# How can I loop through run_query() in Python generating multiple datasets and then multiples CSVs?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So, I'm extracting some datasets from a connection with Datagrip. What I'm doing is generating some tables based on the id numbers and I want to generate CSVs from the result. This is my code up to now:

```
import os
import sqlalchemy

pd.options.display.max_columns = 500
pd.options.display.max_rows = 500
from datetime import timedelta

import psycopg2
import csv

DB_USER = 'XXXXXX'
DB_PASS = 'XXXXXX'
DB_HOST = 'XXXXXX'
DB_PORT =  XXXX
DB_NAME = 'xxxxxx'

def get_engine():
    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_NAME))

def run_query(query_txt):
    engine = get_engine()
    with engine.begin() as con:
        return pd.read_sql(query_txt, con)

df = run_query(
"""
select * from database
where id between 0 and 100000
""")

df.to_csv('data_1.csv', sep= ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, index=False)
```

However, I need to do this several times, for id between 100001 and 200000, 200001 and 300000 and so on. Is there a way to automate this?

Thanks